# JUnit test code stops executing after checking for an exception

Tags: java, junit

This is my test:

```
  import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;
  @Rule
  public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

  @Test
  public void testSearch() {
      List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2});  
      exception.expect(NoSuchElementException.class);   
      SimpleSearch.search(myList, 5);
      System.out.println("here");

      exception.expect(NoSuchElementException.class);  
      assertEquals(1, SimpleSearch.search(myList, 22));
}
```

When I run it, it says it ran 1/1 but it does not print `here` and it does not do any asserts or run any lines below the line `SimpleSearch.search(myList, 5);` (after the exception is caught).

How can I get it to continue after catching an exception (I want to do it inside the same `testSearch` function)?

Comment: Why do you want to continue ?

Comment: @javaguy Because I want to test the rest of the code.

Comment: Move it into a separate method.

Comment: FYI, `Arrays.asList()` accepts a varargs parameter. You can do `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2)`.

Comment: If you really want to use the same method, you can do `try { SimpleSearch.search(myList, 5); fail(); } catch (NoSuchElementException.class) {}`. But I would avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tests should be more granular in this case and split out the 2 test cases

```
  @Test(ExpectedException=NoSuchElementException.class)
  public void testSearch_NotFound() {
      List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2});  
      SimpleSearch.search(myList, 5);
  }

  @Test
  public void testSearch() {
      List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2});  
      assertEquals(1, SimpleSearch.search(myList, 22));
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

The code is working as designed. `ExpectedException` just says: the test should throw this particular exception, but this does **not** mean: *and continue execution*. Any Exception stops the execution of the program at that point. The normal way to bypass this in Java, is to use a `try .. catch` block.

```
@Test
public void testSearch() {

    List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 4, 6, 3, 1, 2});  
    try {
        SimpleSearch.search(myList, 5);
        Assert.fail("Did not find NoSuchElementException!");
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException ex) {
        // ignored
    }
    System.out.println("here");

    // the rest of your code is nonesense
}
```